# Thinkpad keyboard & scrolling

Tags: keyboard, mouse, macos, third-party

I have got an Thinkpad external keyboard with my mac. The keyboard has some mouse buttons and trackpoint. The trackpoint mouse function with two mouse button works fine but scrolling with middle button + trackpoint isn't. Is there any chance to configure scrolling with trackpoint? I have Logitech mouse with scroolwheel, that works out of the box. I use Yosemite.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I do not own this keyboard, so I can only cite others.

In [this Topic](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4693176) some users talk about their experience. It seems to depend on the exact version of the keyboard, that you are using.

- USB-Version:

  > I was able to get the center mouse button scroll to work by installing USB Overdrive. You select "middle button" and change it to "move to scroll"
- Bluetooth-Version:

  > My Lenovo Compact Bluetooth wireless keyboard (Part Number# 0B47190) paired via bluetooth with both my MacBooks quickly, and the middle button used with the red trackpoint on the keyboard scrolls in every situation I can think of (web browsing, doc editing, evernote, MSOffice, Keynote, Pages, etc.) without any addition setup or extra programs like UsbOverdrive.  It just works.