# Scrolling speed on Thinkpad USB keyboard with Trackpoint

Tags: keyboard, macos

I'm using USB Override and bind "Move to scroll" to middle button like suggested in this topic: [link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/162908/thinkpad-keyboard-scrolling). But scrolling speed in this mode is too slow for me and this seems to be independent from cursor speed or any other settings. Can anyone help me to find any settings that manages scrolling speed in "Move to Scroll" mode?

Comment: You are connecting a Thinkpad USB keyboard to your Mac?

Comment: @IconDaemon Of course) I connect it using USB like usual usb-keyboard.